# Understanding async function --> Second function runs to soon

Tags: node.js, async-await, fetch-api

I make a API call to get the token i need for the second function. But this one runs to soon, so no data. (i get a error that there is a unexpected end of json). after this i make 4 ore calls. I made this in google apps script, but the hole script takes about 17 minutes. So i want to create this in NodeJS and deploy on firebase, then create one endpoint for the apps script to get the already prept data.

**FIRST function**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 
const resid = require('./calls.js');


/*
Here we start with the request to get a new token. And pass this on in the request's later on.
*/
async function getToken() {

    const config = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {}
    };

    const url = 'https://theapirurl.com';

    const response = await fetch(url, config);
    const json = await response.json();
    const token = json['access_token'];

    await resid.getReservationIds(token);

}

getToken()
```

**Second function (on calls.js)**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 

async function getReservationIds(token) {

    const url = "https://theapiurl.com";
    const config = {
        
        method: "get",
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "bearer" + token
        }
    };

    const respone = await fetch(url, config);
    const json = await respone.json();

    //console.log(json);

}

module.exports = {
    resid: getReservationIds()
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Now i get this error:

```
(node:43371) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://apiurlfromcallsjs.com reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at /Users/remco/functions/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async getReservationIds (/Users/remco/functions/calls.js:20:18)
(node:43371) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:43371) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:43371) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: getReservationIds is not a function
    at getToken (/Users/remco/functions/index.js:23:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:43371) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're invoking the second function immediately, rather than waiting for the first function to finish:

```
module.exports = {
    resid: getReservationIds()
}
```

So when you run

```
const resid = require('./calls.js');
```

At this point, that second function is already in the process of running (and `resid.getReservationIds` is a Promise, not a function).

Export just the function instead:

```
module.exports = getReservationIds;
```

Then import and call it:

```
const getReservationIds = require('./calls.js');
// ...
  await getReservationIds(token);
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance Now i get a error, i pasted in the original post. But your awnser above makes sense, thank you!

Comment: When i pass in the token as a const in the calls.js it works like a charm. So as far i can tell the token is undifined when the getReservationIds is running.

Comment: If the `token` isn't defined, then nothing exists at `json['access_token']`. Examine the response to figure out the right property you need to access to get the token.

Comment: Also note that to set an authorization header, you need a space after `Bearer` before the token - that is, you probably want `"Authorization": "Bearer " + token`

Comment: When i log the token before i call the getReservationId i get first the error above end then the token in my terminal. (token is correct and working) So i think the getReservationId is running before the the getToken is finised. Like i said. If i pass the token as a const inside the getReservationId function and do: node calls.js it works